# How to search through a table and pull the data?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm new to js, I'm working on a chrome extension and am having confusion webscraping a website. Suppose I have a simple table in an html like this

```
<html>
  <body>      
    <table class="birthdays">   
      <tbody><tr>
        <th>date</th>
        <th>month</th>
        <th>year</th>
      </tr> 
    
    <tr class="r0">
      <td>Person</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Jan</td>
      <td>77</td>
      <td colspan="3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="r0">
    <td>Person</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Jan</td>
      <td>77</td>
      <td colspan="3"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody></table>
  </body>
</html>
```

In my chrome extension when I do

```
const x = document.getElementsByTagName("th")[0][0]
alert(x)
```

It says it found a th object, but doesn't give me the actual data. That's the first issue, my actual goal is to determine if all elements in the tr tags have the same of one property (ex. if everyone has their birthday in Jan, open a tab).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementsByTagName`
returns HTMLCollection https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection

it's an array-like object (not real array)
and you can get the value from it calling `item()` method https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection/item

Seems that you need something like this `document.getElementsByTagName("th").item(0).innerHTML` to get content of the first TH tag

Comment: How would I be able to look at a list of all the <td> tags I want? I want to create a list with the 3rd element of each <tr> class.

Comment: It wouldbe  better to use selector in this case```document.querySelectorAll("tr td:nth-child(3)")```

Answer (score 1):

This  is not a complete answer, but in javascript the container is not its contents - i.e. you need document.getElementsByTagName("th")[0][0].innerHTML to get at the 'date' string.